# conic section about circular cylindrical can

Tags: calculus

if we want to construct a circular cylindrical can of height H cm and the capacity of V cm^3 find the inner radius r of the can?
......  guys i have not got any idea about this from my book calculus by EAEL W.SWAKOWSKI than I i visited mathemetica but i only found its formula but i could not find derivation of that formula and main purpose behind the use of that fomula please any one can guide me with full satisfied information.....?

Comment: What formulas do you know which you think may be relevant? Can you edit your post and write them there?

Comment: Web search for volume of cylinder.